# Ubuntu doesn't detect microphone

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.10, sound-card, microphone

The built in microphone of my Dell Inspiron 1525 is working fine in Windows. But it is not getting detected in Ubuntu. What can I do to make it functional.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Usual way of resolving sound problems with new hardware is to install development version of ALSA.